# how to instantiate an object within another object and then call methods from the second object (python)

Tags: object, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list

i have the following code:

class Commit:

```
id = 0
commits = []

def __init__(self, message=None, changes=None):
    Commit.id += 1
    self.id = Commit.id
    self.message = tuple([message])
    self.changes = tuple(changes)
    Commit.commits.append(self.message + self.changes)
    self.commits = Commit.commits
    self.next = None
```

class Branch:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.tail = None
    self.head = None

def new_commit(self, commit):
    if not self.head:
        self.head = commit
        self.tail = self.head
    else:
        self.tail.next = commit
        self.tail = self.tail.next
```

class Repository:

```
branches = {}

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.branches = Repository.branches
def branch(self, branch_name):
    self.branch_name = Branch()
    self.branches[branch_name] = self.branch_name
    return self.branches[branch_name]
```

but when i do this to instantiate it:

```
    repo = Repository("syllabus 2.0")
    repo.branch("master").new_commit(Commit(message="add readme", changes=[("CREATE", "README.md")]))
    print(repo.branch("master").head)
```

it prints None 
Why is this happening?

Comment: You create a new `Branch` *every time you call `.branch`* - why?!

Comment: .branch is supposed to create a new branch instance under that branch name every time i call .branch

Comment: But that makes no sense - how can you ever get back to the previous version? Every time you access a given branch it's a brand new object.

Comment: yeah i realized that and it was because of that , that when i called the branch it wouldn't work thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

never mind fixed it with

```
def branch(self, branch_name):
    if branch_name not in self.branches:
        self.branches[branch_name] = Branch()
        return self.branches[branch_name]
    else:
        return self.branches[branch_name]
```

Comment: if you have answered your question yourself, you should accept your answer (which is not only allowed but encouraged) so others can also benefit from it.